# Forge Viewer - What is the concept of layer on markups?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Can someone give an idea about the use of layers/ layerid while drawing markups? How that will be useful?
I didnt find any proper explanation of layer concept in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layerId` is Identifier for the layer of markups to be edited/restored, just so loaded markups are grouped and manageable, e.g. to show/hide a layers when in view mode :

```
markupExt.show/hideMarkups('layerId')
```

Hence with `markupExt.svgLayersMap` you'd be able to manage loaded markups:

```
markExt.svgLayersMap['layerId'].markups[index] // access loaded markups
```

Comment: can you please share some example or tutorial which deals layers idea in detail

Comment: unfortunately we don't have anything as such - stay tuned to our official Forge blog we might put some writings together on that front in the future